# Check how far positions in list to straight line

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, graphics

I have a list of  X and Y positions, I do not know what the length of the list.

I want to create a straight line only by use the first and last position in the list.

Then, I want to check how far the other positions are from this line, something similar to residuals in statistics.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you need RegionDistance

```
pts = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {5, 2}]
(*{{70, 76}, {25, 47}, {47, 65}, {19, 99}, {73, 11}}*)

line = Line[{pts[[1]], pts[[-1]]}]
(*Line[{{70, 76}, {73, 11}}]*)

RegionDistance[line] /@ pts // N
(*{0., 46.2892, 23.4827, 55.9464, 0.}*)
```

Comment: A minute and 52 seconds difference this time!!!

Comment: lol. I'm old and slow.

Comment: I feel older than [`this dude`](https://i.imgflip.com/1kjlcb.jpg) to be honest :-) Now I have to make my tea and eat my cookies

Comment: RegionDistance is listable, and will also work more quickly with machine numbers data instead of integer data, so `RegionDistance[line][N @ pts]` ought to be much faster for a lot of points.

Answer (score 6):

(I hope the Statistics gods forgive me for this...)

```
(* Generate the data a la @bmf *)
SeedRandom[12345];
n = 10;
xdata = RandomReal[10, n];
ydata = RandomReal[10, n];
list = Thread@{xdata, ydata}

(* Construct weights with the first and last values having weight 1 and the rest 0 *)
w = Join[{1}, ConstantArray[0, n - 2], {1}]

(* Perform regression (a la @Syed) and obtain residuals of points with weight 0 *)
lm = LinearModelFit[list, x, x, Weights -> w]
lm["FitResiduals"][[2 ;; n - 1]]
(* {-0.368952, 1.21697, 2.67673, 2.14409, 0.345137, -3.68814, -0.228145, -4.84022} *)
```

And as a check, see that the first and last points have essentially a zero residual:

```
lm["FitResiduals"]
(* {8.88178*10^-16, -0.368952, 1.21697, 2.67673, 2.14409, 0.345137, -3.68814, -0.228145, -4.84022,
    -8.88178*10^-16} *)
```

Comment: In essence, the question is posed essentially as a geometry problem, not a statistics one. So maybe you're safe. Or maybe they'll throw you in the pit with all the outliers. :)

Comment: OTOH, if by "how far" the OP does not mean the residuals but the Euclidean distance, it may be the geometry gods you will answer to....(?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks.  I just wanted to show that I could abuse statistical procedures, too.  (Although maybe not as grossly as I have witnessed in my long career.)  (And "outliers" might actually be the good data!)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good point about the Euclidean distance.  Someone else can address that issue.

Comment: Fristly nicely done Jim. Cool approach. Secondly, don't worry about the gods of statistics too much. Statistically speaking they'll be busy judging undergrads that solve problems resulting in probabilities bigger than 1 :)

Answer (score 4):

Usually you don't seek to join the first and last point of your dataset as any of these could be an outlier. With that said,

```
SeedRandom[1];
alist = Sort@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {30, 2}]
lm = LinearModelFit[alist, x, x]
Show[
 ListPlot[alist, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[Normal@lm, {x, -1, 1}
  , PlotStyle -> {Thick, Darker@Green}]
 ]
```

[image]

```
lm["FitResiduals"]
```

> ```
> {-0.314089, 0.020965, 0.103345, 0.575525, -0.786464, 0.183661, \
> -0.49513, -0.0228533, 0.514558, 0.27952, -0.50779, 0.741431, \
> 0.0193917, 0.503151, -0.39931, 0.565423, 0.726498, -0.543778, \
> 0.0493962, -0.416437, 0.2469, -0.616125, -0.447185, 1.09729, \
> -0.470928, -0.822542, -0.31986, -0.620065, 0.327262, 0.828236}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

This is a rather clumsy and inelegant post. `RegionDistance` and exploiting linear regression (residuals) achieves goal efficiently. `Quiet` hides some numerical issues. I post it just to illustrate another way (albeit uninspiring):

```
func[p_, ln_] := Module[{s, r},
  s = {x, y} /. Solve[{({x, y} - p) . ({x, y} - p) == r, ln}, {x, y}];
  {Chop[Sqrt[r]], {p, s[[1]]}} /. 
   Solve[s[[1, 1]] == s[[2, 1]], r][[1]]]
rf[] := Module[{rand = RandomReal[10, {20, 2}], exp, ans},
  exp = Eliminate[{x, y} == (rand[[-1]] - rand[[1]]) t + rand[[1]], t];
  ans = Quiet[Re[Chop[func[#, exp] & /@ rand]]];
  Graphics[{InfiniteLine[rand[[{1, -1}]]], Point[rand], Red, 
      PointSize[0.02], Point[rand[[{1, -1}]]], Blue, #}] & /@ {, 
    Arrow /@ ans[[All, 2]], {Arrow /@ ans[[All, 2]], 
     Text[Framed[NumberForm[#1, 2], Background -> White], Mean@#2] & @@@
       ans}}]
```

`func` calculates radius of circle tangent to line with centre as point of interest. `rf` is just window dressing for 20  random points.

A few examples:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following is an extended comment and is only meant to get you started. Also note, that I find confusing your last question. Do you want the functionality of residuals? Something similar you said, but what do you mean? Anyway, the following should give you some idea what to look up in the docs.

Creating random `x` and `y` points

```
xdata = RandomReal[10, 10];
ydata = RandomReal[10, 10];
```

Make a list of points

```
list = Thread@{xdata, ydata}
```

> [image: list]

Get the length of the list

```
Length@list
```

> 10

and the dimensions

```
Dimensions@list
```

> {10, 2}

Choose the first and last `{x,y}` pairs of the list and plot a line

```
Graphics[Line[{First@list, Last@list}]]
```

> [image: line]

You can plot all points and the line to see how the situation looks

```
Show[ListPlot[list, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Graphics[Line[{First@list, Last@list}]]]
```

> [image: plot]

Finally, for the distance you can do something like

```
Table[RegionDistance[Line[{First@list, Last@list}], list[[xx]]], {xx, 
  1, 10}]
```

> [image: distance]

not sure if that's what you wanted, though.